# OpenCV Error when initializing tracker object

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have been trying to implement a tracker (CSRT) in OpenCV with C++ but I got an error when the

`tracker->init(firstframe, boundingbox)` part is executed.

Here is the error message below,

> ..../opencv/modules/core/src/merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion
>   failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function
>   'merge'

and here is my code. Btw, I am working on Jetson Nano and I had to do some type conversion from float* to cv::Mat.

```
cv::Mat first_frame;
float* first_imgRGBA = NULL;
camera->CaptureRGBA(&first_imgRGBA, 1000, 1);
first_frame = cv::Mat(camera->GetHeight(), camera->GetWidth(), CV_32FC4, first_imgRGBA);
first_frame /= 255;
cv::cvtColor(first_frame, first_frame, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
Rect2d bbox(287, 23, 86, 320);
rectangle(first_frame, bbox, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 2, 1 );   
imshow("Tracking", first_frame);
tracker->init(first_frame, bbox);
```

Thank you.